# How to get corresponding class name; from a common class name in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

How to Class Name mentioned on right of other class name in Jquery?

```
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-5 showOnload phoneId">
</div> /// It contains two classes of Pure and two custom classes.
</div>
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-5 showOnload addressId">
</div>
</div>
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-5 showOnload nameId">
</div>
</div>
```

on base of showOnload i want to get class name phoneId, addressId and nameId (not pure css classes).
Possible JQuery code might be

```
$('.showOnload').each(function() {
    //this.classname on right i.e Phone Id, Address Id and name Id    
});
```

**Update**: As mates asked what i am trying to achieve is: If div have showOnload then i have to expand a div(Show/Hide) with id=phoneId or addressId.

Comment: You can use `hasClass` to check if element has certain class

Comment: I'm not sure that any solution based on a position in the `className` property, the `class` attribute or in the `classList` is guaranteed cross-browser. Will the relevant classes always end with `Id`?

Comment: @Tushar
Can you give me an example?

Comment: This is clearly an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/xy-problem/info).  Try to tell us what you are trying to achieve, as there is undoubtedly a better way.

Comment: "*[I] have to expand a div (Show/Hide) with id=phoneId or addressId*" - but no elements have an `id`.

Comment: @fatherazrael see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cjkhgvp7/

Answer (score 2):

You can try a simple regex like

```
$('.showOnload').each(function () {
    var clazz = this.className.match(/\w+Id\b/)[0]
});
```

---

Based on the update

```js
$('.showOnload').click(function() {
  var match = this.className.match(/\w+Id\b/);
  if (match) {
    $('#' + match[0]).toggle();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-5 showOnload phoneId">phoneId</div>
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-5 showOnload addressId">addressId</div>
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-5 showOnload nameId">nameId</div>
<hr />
<div id="phoneId">phoneId</div>
<div id="addressId">addressId</div>
<div id="nameId">nameId</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That Snippet helped me in moving forward. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) as follow:

```
$('.showOnload').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('phoneId')) { // Check if having class phoneId
        alert('It has class phoneId');
    }
});
```

You can also use `regex` and `indexOf()` as follow:

```
$('.showOnload').each(function() {
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(/\s+/); // Split by spaces
    if (classes.indexOf('phoneId') > -1) {
        alert('It has class phoneId');
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

Use [`attribute selector`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to limit the matching elements.

```
$('div[class$="Id"]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('phoneId')) { // Check if having class phoneId
        alert('It has class phoneId');
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

> If div have showOnload then i have to expand a div(Show/Hide) with id=phoneId or addressId.

```
$('div.showOnload[class$="Id"]').toggle();
```

Comment: But it is double check, Like if i have 10 divs like that then i need to hard code them in javascript too? Can't we get class name on right of that?

Comment: I want to check if div with this class name (showOnload) exists in whole page; then expand(Hide/show) another div with id "phoneId".

Comment: @fatherazrael Yes, that'll be better

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82091/discussion-between-tushar-and-fatherazrael).

Comment: @fatherazrael Please check `UPDATE` in answer

Answer (score 0):

Use either,

```
$('.showOnload.phoneId').each(function() {
    get all phone id
});
```

Or

```
$('.showOnload').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("phoneId")) {
    }
});
```

Comment: But it is double check, Like if i have 10 divs like that then i need to hard code them in javascript too? Can't we get class name on right of that?